# PHP Export to CSV class

Tags: php, csv

I have written the following class to export database results to a CSV file.

```
<?php
class Export {
    public static function tocsv($results = array(), $fields = array()) {
        $schema_insert = '"'.implode('","', $fields).'"';
        $out .= $schema_insert."\n";

        foreach($results as $row) {
            $schema_insert = '';
            $schema_insert .= '"'.$row->week_ending.'",';
            $schema_insert .= '"'.$row->project.'",';
            $schema_insert .= '"'.$row->employee.'",';
            $schema_insert .= '"'.$row->plots.'",';
            $schema_insert .= '"'.$row->categories.'"';
            $out .= $schema_insert."\n";
        }
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        echo $out;
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

The output is:

```
"Week ending","Project name","Plot numbers","Categories","Employee"
"Friday 08 May 2015","Big Road","Tracey Smith","1A, 2A, 3A"," Water meter, 1st fix inc lagging"
```

However, when I open with Excel everything is in one column.  Have I missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: try using \n\r instead of \n

Comment: Thanks, already tried this but same result.

Comment: why not just use fputcsv ? also where are you defining $filename?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to define a filename, it works now.  Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a semicolon as your fieldterminator instead of a comma, it's an Excel thing really, not a php thing.